# PHP Threading and high-latency file access (eg; FTP)

Tags: php, multithreading, resources

This is a bit complicated, so please don't jump to conclusions, feel free to ask about anything that is not clear enough.

Basically, I have a websocket server written in PHP. Please note that websocket messages are asynchronous, that is, a response to a request might take a lot of time, all the while the client keeps on working (if applicable).

Clients are supposed to ask the server for access to files on other servers. This can be an FTP service, or Dropbox, for the matter.

Here, please take note of two issues: **connections should be shared and reused** and **the server actually 'freezes' while it does its work**, hence any requests are processed after the server has 'unfrozen'.

Therefore, I thought, why not offload file access (which is what freezes the server) to [PHP threads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpthreadlib/)?

The problem here is twofold;

- how do I make a connection resource in the main thread (the server) available to the sub threads (not possible with the above threading model)?
- what would happen if two threads end up needing the same resource? It's perfectly fine if one is locked until the other one finishes, but we still need to figure out issue #1.

Perhaps my train of thought is all screwed up, if you can find a better solution, I'm eager to hear it out. I've also had the idea of having a PHP thread hosting a connection resource, but it's pretty memory intensive.

Comment: You might be able to get this to work in PHP, but I might suggest using another server-side technology, such as Node.JS, or something that actually supports multithreading in a more direct way.  If you go the Node route, you don't have to actually write any threaded code... it does all of that work for you by running your code in a single thread, but handling IO in a multithreaded way behind the scenes.  Of course, you still have the problem of maintaining a connection pool to external resources, but at least your code will be able to see that pool without passing it over IPC.

Comment: I've thought about Node.js a long time ago, and it's neither helpful nor does it decrease any code for my cause. In fact, it increases maintenance and decreases choice of server providers (no, I don't need a fancy cloud provider for such a measly little personal app).

Comment: I also have another issue which would have applied to  node.js just the same; how would I share connections between different threads?

Comment: You would simply store an array or some kind of collection of connections to your external resources, and access them as needed.  In PHP, you're going to have to find a way to share such a collection between processes, where with Node, anything can easily be shared by its very nature of everything being served from the same process.

Comment: Both in PHP and node, it would suffer the same issues, namely threads accessing the same resources concurrently.

Comment: Yes, no doubt.  I'm just saying that you will have a pool of idle connections that you will need to share between different processes in PHP, and having all of them available in a single process fixes that problem.

Comment: That would be a great idea if it weren't that connections in the same process will block the process from responding to other requests, even for different connections. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11238/discussion-between-brad-and-christian)

Answer (score 5):

PHP supports no threads. The purpose of PHP is to respond to web requests quickly. That's what the architecture was built for. Different libraries try to do something like threads but they usually cause more issues than they solve.

In general there are two ways to achieve what you want:

- off-load the long processes to an external process. A common approach is using a system like gearman http://php.net/gearman
- Use asynchronous operations. Some stream operations and such provide an "async" flag or "non-blocking" mode. http://php.net/stream-set-blocking

Comment: I'll check out gearman, hope it doesn't have the same limitations as phpthreadlib. Regarding asynch operations; the problem is that they miss out on certain key aspects, for example, there is no way to make `ftp_rawlist()` async.